# Using a getter with a smart pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

Let's say I have the following class:

```
#include "ClassB.h"
#include <memory>

    class A
    {

      private:
        std::shared_ptr<ClassB> aClassB;

      public:
        ClassA();
        virtual ~ClassA();

        std::shared_ptr<ClassB> getClassB() const{
             return ClassB;
         }
    };
```

Now I can call `ClassA.getClassB()` to obtain the smart pointer that points to member variable `aClassB`. However, the problem is that I can use this smart pointer to actually change member variable `aClassB`, which I don't want. So basically I want to implement something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<const ClassB> getClassB() const{
                 return ClassB;
```

However, this does not work because `aClassB` is not a `const`. I don't want to make `aClassB` a constant within `classA`, because there are member functions of `ClassA` that should be able to update this aClassB member variable.

Any suggestions how I can get `aClassB` using the get functions within other classes, but without allowing changes made to `aClassB` from other classes.

Comment: [Hmm?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc7f9b682bdaa80a)

Comment: Please post code you have in fact tried to compile.

Comment: @nos [Hmm?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a154b35650db9a7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a `std::shared_ptr<const ClassB>`

```
//#include "ClassB.h"
struct ClassB
{
    int i = 0;
};

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class ClassA
{

private:
    std::shared_ptr<ClassB> aClassB;

public:
    ClassA() :aClassB(new ClassB) { aClassB->i = 1; }
    virtual ~ClassA(){}

    std::shared_ptr<const ClassB> getClassB() const {
        return aClassB;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    //a.getClassB()->i = 2; //error: you cannot assign to a variable that is const
    std::cout << a.getClassB()->i << std::endl; //Works    
}
```

As you see `aClassB` is not const within `ClassA`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want the shared pointer in the interface, when not sharing?

If you just want to allow reading the value of `ClassB` you can do

```
const ClassB& getClassB() const {
   return *aClassB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to return a `const ClassB&:

```
const ClassB& getClassB() const {
    return *aClassB;
}
```

Comment: That would prevent changing what the pointer points to. Not the actual pointee. (Much like `const int*` vs `int* const`)

Comment: Noted: maybe return a const ref instead?